# Styling Drop Down Menus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am new to using drop down's and am wondering what the best approach is to styling drop-down fields. I essentially am looking to style the before view and then a custom style for the selection menu that appears when you click on it. Any suggestions?

[Unstyled Dropdown Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H62F.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the class name of the dropdown menu and children selector. Use List for dropdown menu instead of form "select". If you're using bootstrap you might have to use multiple class name and combinators between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the `<select>` tag but you can't style `<option>`.